# How to use Sequences in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am still new to SQL and I am in the learning phase.  I have a homework assignment which I've been working on for quite some time and I cannot figure out where my error lies from within the sequences.  I am using Oracle SQL.

```sql
INSERT INTO ORDERS
VALUES (SEQ_ORDER_ID.NEXTVAL, '200', 'MOVIE FOR RENT', '30', '322.61', '15.36', 'CP',          '10-MAR-13', '15-MAR-13');
INSERT INTO ORDERS
VALUES (SEQ_ORDER_ID.NEXTVAL, '200', 'MOVIE FOR RENT', '30', '419.74', '19.99', 'CP',         '12-MAR-13', '17-MAR-13');

INSERT INTO ORDER_ITEMS
VALUES (SEQ_ITEM_ID.NEXTVAL, SEQ_ORDER_ID.CURRVAL, '40', '10', '25', '12.29', '307.25');
INSERT INTO ORDER_ITEMS
VALUES (SEQ_ITEM_ID.NEXTVAL, SEQ_ORDER_ID.CURRVAL, '40', '11', '25', '15.99',     '399.75');
```

Order_id and Item_id I would like to sequence with NEXTVAL and CURRVAL.  The error I am getting is:

```
VALUES (SEQ_ITEM_ID.NEXTVAL, SEQ_ORDER_ID.CURRVAL, '40', '10', '25', '12.29', '307.25')
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02289: sequence does not exist 


VALUES (SEQ_ITEM_ID.NEXTVAL, SEQ_ORDER_ID.CURRVAL, '40', '11', '25', '15.99', '399.75')
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

Thanks for your help.

Here is a little more information...

```
create table orders(
order_id                number(8),
Store_id                number(4) not null,  
description             varchar2(30),
total_items             number(3),
total_payment           number(8,2),
tax                     number(6,2),
order_status            varchar2(2),
ordering_date           date,
order_completed_date    date
);

create table order_items(
item_id                   number(10),
order_id                  number(8) not null,
distribution_id           number(8) not null,
movie_id                  number(5) not null, 
number_of_items           number(3),
item_unit_price           number(5,2),
item_sub_total            number(10,2)
);

alter table orders 
add constraint order_pk primary key (order_id);

alter table orders   
add constraint store_order_fk foreign key (store_id) references        movie_rental_stores(store_id);

alter table order_items 
add constraint order_item_pk primary key (item_id);

alter table order_items
add constraint order_item_fk foreign key (order_id) references orders(order_id);

alter table order_items   
add constraint movie_item_fk foreign key (movie_id) references movies(movie_id);

alter table order_items
add constraint distributor_order_item_fk foreign key (distribution_id) references   distributed_movie_list(distribution_id);

DROP sequence seq_order_id;
CREATE sequence seq_order_id 
increment BY 1 START WITH 1 minvalue 1;

DROP sequence seq_order_item_id;
CREATE sequence seq_order_item_id 
increment BY 1 START WITH 1 minvalue 1;
```

Comment: @William Peterson, you have created `seq_order_item_id` sequence, but you are trying to use `seq_item_id` in your code.

Comment: This question is about a typo in the posted code

Comment: @APC, Where is the typo in the code?  What did I do wrong?  I still do not quite understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ORA-02289 is correct.  The sequence does not exist.  Look at your code more closely.
Your DDL script creates a sequence with this name ...

```
DROP sequence seq_order_item_id;
CREATE sequence seq_order_item_id
```

... but your code references this name:

```
VALUES (SEQ_ITEM_ID.NEXTVAL
```

Just change your INSERT statements so they reference the correct name and the code will run.

Comment: and @Horrendous_Space_Kablooie, thank you...thank you...thank you...I finally understand what you have been trying to tell me to do.  My code worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Are created the sequence SEQ_ITEM_ID in the same schema that the table orders?

have created public synonym by SEQ_ITEM_ID?

Comment: The tables are within the same schema.  I don't understand "public synonym."  So, I'm not sure how to answer that question.

Comment: He did not ask if the tables where in the same schema, but rather, are the tables AND the sequence objects in the same schema?  I don't see how they could be, or you would not get this error.  Please show your create statements.  A public synonym is an alias to an object that is global to all schemas.  You should not need that if all your objects are in the same schema.